# Python Multiprocessing - How to implement a shared counter and Queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have the following Python3 Code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, JoinableQueue, Value
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

def test():
    global numfail
    global queue
    while not queue.empty():
        number = queue.get()
        with numfail.get_lock():
            numfail.value += number
        queue.task_done()

def startthreads():
    global numfail
    global queue
    queue = JoinableQueue()
    for i in range(100):
        numfail = Value('i',0)
        for j in range(10):
            queue.put(j)
        for j in range(10):
            Process(target=test, args=[]).start()

        queue.join()
        print(i, numfail.value)

numfail = 0
startthreads()
```

The output should be 45 every time, however sometimes some values dont get added to the sum and sometimes there is a deadlock.

I also tried it with a manager:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, JoinableQueue, Value
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

def test():
    global numfail
    global queue
    while not queue.empty():
        number = queue.get()
        numfail.value += number
        queue.task_done()

def startthreads():
    global numfail
    global queue
    queue = JoinableQueue()
    manager = SyncManager()
    manager.start()
    for i in range(100):
        numfail = manager.Value('i',0)
        for j in range(10):
            queue.put(j)
        for j in range(10):
            Process(target=test, args=[]).start()

        queue.join()
        print(i, numfail.value)

numfail = 0
startthreads()
```

But then I get the following error

```
Process Process-281:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "MT.py", line 9, in test
    numfail.value += number
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 1154, in get
    return self._callmethod('get')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 850, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 250, in serve_client
    self.id_to_local_proxy_obj[ident]
KeyError: '7f8da01ff310'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 252, in serve_client
    raise ke
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 246, in serve_client
    obj, exposed, gettypeid = id_to_obj[ident]
KeyError: '7f8da01ff310'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Process Process-280:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "MT.py", line 9, in test
    numfail.value += number
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 1154, in get
    return self._callmethod('get')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 850, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 250, in serve_client
    self.id_to_local_proxy_obj[ident]
KeyError: '7f8da01ff310'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 252, in serve_client
    raise ke
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 246, in serve_client
    obj, exposed, gettypeid = id_to_obj[ident]
KeyError: '7f8da01ff310'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Process Process-275:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "MT.py", line 9, in test
    numfail.value += number
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 1154, in get
    return self._callmethod('get')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 850, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 250, in serve_client
    self.id_to_local_proxy_obj[ident]
KeyError: '7f8da01ff310'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 252, in serve_client
    raise ke
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 246, in serve_client
    obj, exposed, gettypeid = id_to_obj[ident]
KeyError: '7f8da01ff310'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I fix my problem or how can I implement this in another way, so that I can send the "tasks" in a queue to another function and have that function work through all items and increase a variable for each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of global variables and pass them to the child process as arguments.

Also, you can use the SyncManager proxy for Queue:

```
queue = manager.Queue()
```

Consider using a Pool as well.